# how to extract Random forest model and predict using a set of predictor vector

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am creating some sort of an "image" recognizing model. 
I have variables `X_1`, `X_2`, `X_3`, `X_4` and `X_5`(height, skin color, eyecolor, haircolor, nose shape)and a variable `Y`(enthnicity) to predict.
After feeding the data into the random forest, how can i predict the values of Y?
I have an instance `[x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5]` as values for `[X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5]`, how can i get the respective `Y`?

Comment: What module are you using, if any? (`scikit-learn`? `tensorflow`?)

Comment: i am using scikit learn

Comment: Can you update your question to include your current code? I can't help without seeing that.

Comment: Call "predict" on a dataset? :)